# İ need help for ffmpeg Merge 2 videos

Tags: ffmpeg

the code I wrote below takes two video files renders them into 1080p res, plays the 1st video for some time (5 secs) then plays the 2nd video foreground with the first video's audio still playing in the background.

The length of the second video is taken as basis duration.  If 2nd video's duration is shorter than 1st one, video freezes and audio keeps playing. If 2nd video is longer than the 1st, video continues in accordance with 1st video duration.

```
string ar = $"-y -i \"{videoModel.dosya_yolu}\" -i \"video.mp4\" -filter_complex \"[1:v] scale=1920:1080 [a]; [0:v] scale=1920:1080 [b]; [b] [a] overlay=enable=gte(t\\,{baslangic}):x=0:y=0:shortest=1[out]\" -map [out] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy \"{cikti}\"";
```

What I want to do is:

1. if the 2nd video is shorter,  it should start again and keep playing until the 1st video ends, and not freeze
2. Even though each video is around 800mb, it renders out 4-5gb. It needs to be minimized without decreasing resolution
3. it shouldn't modify resolution unless both videos have different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

İ handle it

1-

`string ar = $"-y -i \"{videoModel.dosya_yolu}\" -stream_loop -1 -i  \"video.mp4\" -filter_complex \"[1:v] scale=1920:1080 [a]; [0:v] scale=1920:1080 [b]; [b] [a] overlay=enable=gte(t\\,{baslangic}):x=0:y=0:shortest=1[out]\" -map [out] -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -preset veryslow -c:a copy \"{cikti}\"";`